# Video breakup problems with high power using The Force VTX?

Tags: troubleshooting, video-transmitters

I normally fly with my VTX on 200mw but sometimes I need it to be more powerful. Whenever I turn it to a higher power setting, though, the video becomes worse. When I set it to 600mw, the video seems to lose some color and turn black and white at times. Also, very faint lines (white lines, not black lines) appear in the video feed. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

This is happening on BNF 4s Nazgul5. The VTX is The Force VT5804 V2.

Comment: Where are you when this happens? Indoors, outside, proximity to buildings?

Comment: Outside, not really near any buildings.

Comment: Huh, that's odd. What's your VTX/goggle setup and antennae?

Comment: I have the Skyzone 02X goggles with two pagoda antennae. The VTX is the FORCE VT5804 V2. The antenna on the VTX is the iFlight doom Antenna.

Comment: Do the polarizations of your mushroom antennae match? RHCP vs. LHCP.

Comment: Yes, the VTX has RHCP and both of the antennae on the goggles are RHCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be caused by too much heat building up in the VTX causing the electronics to suffer. Try mounting the VTX to have more airflow around it or put a heat sink on it. Sometimes a VTX just can't handle its own output power.

Another issue might be that electronic noise from the VTX is getting fed back into the video signal at the camera or FC connection point. Adding capacitors to various voltage rails sometimes can help.

Still another issue could be that the VTX is drawing too much power from the regulator that is supplying it. Try connecting the VTX directly to Vbat if it can take the higher voltage.

In general, noise in the video signal is the bane of FPV video problems. It can be a bit of black magic to fix.